# Can't get Out-GridView to display two objects

Tags: powershell

I have two objects $A & $B that each contain a CSV import.
Within both objects two columns exist that share the same property name (`DisplayName` & `LoginName`). First of all, I want to combine those and at some point within my script pipe them to `Out-GridView`.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to do that.

```
$A = Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\[...]" | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*[...]*"} | Sort DisplayName
$B = Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\[...]" | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*[...]*"} | Sort DisplayName

$displayNames = ($A.DisplayName) + ($B.DisplayName)
$loginNames = ($A.UserPrincipalName) + ($B.LoginName)
```

Now, at this point I can't use both `$displayNames` and `$loginNames` and simultaneously pipe them to `Out-GridView`.

I was thinking of combining the two objects but doing `$displayNames + $loginNames` results in an object that doesn't maintain the two properties.

Then I thought I could create a pscustomobject like so:

```
$combined = [pscustomobject] @{
DisplayNames = $displayNames
LoginNames = $loginNames
}
```

However, if I piped this into `Out-GridView` it would show me the two columns `DisplayNames` and `LoginNames` but all the values would be within an array so the output would only display one line.

Then I tried to convert both arrays into strings like so:

```
$combined = [pscustomobject] @{
DisplayNames = ($displayNames | Out-String)
LoginNames = ($loginNames | Out-String)
}
```

This time, I was almost there. `Out-GridView` indeed shows the expanded values in the two columns. Unfortunately, they could not be selected with the mouse anymore.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Thats because the way you did it, you make a single row, containing all that information. You you look at the array, it will only say you have 2 columns, and 1 row.

Comment: Look at [`Join-object`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/07/13/join-object/) to help get both of those list connected on the property you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two arrays and all the nonsense of sorting them and trying to keep them in sync, plus the effort to joining them back for output, use a psobject instead with which can append the second files results to the first one. Something like this:

```
$results = Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\[...]" | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*[...]*"} | % {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    LoginName = $_.UserPrincipalName
  }
}

$results += Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\[...]" | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*[...]*"} | % {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    LoginName = $_.LoginName
  }
}

$results | Out-GridView
```

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you. Appending the second Import-csv's properties to the first one was probably what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
$displayNames = @('aaa','bbb','ccc'); 
$loginNames=@('xxx','yyy','zzz'); 
($displayNames | select @{n='NameType';e={'display'}},@{n='Name';e={$_}}) + 
($loginNames | select @{n='NameType';e={'login'}},@{n='Name';e={$_}}) | 
Out-GridView
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could make that work too, but the answer above was the more immediate answer to my problem.